# how to add location to video to be uploaded from iOS using Youtube API3.0.

Tags: ios, youtube-api

i found this class GTLYouTubeGeoPoint from Youtube API 3.0. now i want to add Geo location to the video to be uploaded. any one have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The specific field that you need to set is [`videos.recordingDetails.location`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location). It has subfields for `latitude`, `longitude`, and optionally `elevation`.

You should be able to set it in a similar manner to how you set the other fields in the video's metadata (e.g. `videos.snippet.title`, etc.). Be sure that you include "recordingDetails" in a comma-separated string for the `part=` parameter, along with "snippet" (and "status" if you're setting that too).

Comment: yup, i already did the same, i have this--> GTLYouTubeGeoPoint* recordingDetails = [[ GTLYouTubeGeoPoint alloc]init]; recordingDetails.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.030000]; recordingDetails.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:72.580000]; and for adding location i have this--> video.recordingDetails.location = recordingDetails; and in PART i have this as u said part:@"snippet,status, recordingDetails"...But its not working. its not giving any error video is uploaded successfully but when i look into the location on youtube its blank.

Comment: I was just able to test this out successfully via Python (modifying https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_video) and the video I uploaded did have the location properly set, so this is not an issue with the API. What's the id of the video you uploaded? How are you checking to see whether the location is set? I don't think it's publicly visible on the video's watch page anymore.

Comment: Finally got it, in Obj-C Youtube API 3.0, we have to make object of   GTLYouTubeVideoRecordingDetails class and set lat, lon for it, and then assign it to  video.recordingDetails. ny ways, thanks a lot :)